# how to make use of multiple processors with Node.js?

Tags: node.js

[This](http://www.nodebeginner.org/#head4) says that node.js runs on a single thread. If this is true and node.js is really single-threaded, how can i take advantage of multiple processors?

Or shouldn't I? Because [this](http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-node-js:4bd98440-45e4-4a9a-8ef7-0f7ecbdd56cb) suggests it's actually an advantage.

Can someone point me further explanations to this? I got a little bit confused. thanks (:

Comment: I didn't found that one. Voted to close it myself :p

Comment: NodeJs now has worker thread to do parallel processing  https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html